# Pythonically adding a column to an innitially empty matrix in a loop

Tags: python, numpy

I am newish to python and struggling to do this, despite the fact that it feels like a really basic thing to do.

here is my attempt

```
max_depth_vars = np.linspace(5, 1, 12)
n_mdvs         = len(max_depth_vars)
predictions    = np.array

for index, max_depth_var in zip(range(0,n_mdvs),max_depth_vars):
    # Instantiate model 
    rf = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=max_depth_var)
    # Train the model on training data
    rf.fit(X_train, Y_train)

    predictions= np.column_stack((np.array(predictions), np.array(rf.predict(X_train))))
```

the array `predictions` starts as empty outside the loop then columns are added to it in the loop - or at least that's what I wanted. What I get is:

*ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 1 and the array at index 1 has size 361*

on the final line

How do you pythonically add columns to an initially empty matrix in a loop?

Comment: you can use a list, add to the list during the loop and convert the list to a np.array after finishing the loop

Comment: `np.array` is a function, not a "empty array".  Don't naively imitate list methods in numpy.  For iterations like this, it's better to collect the results in a list, and make the array with one call at the end.  Did you get an error with this attempt?  Try to understand it?

Comment: just added the warning

Comment: The error traceback shows the error occurs in `np.concatenate`.  `np.array(np.array)` is a 0d object dtype array.  `np.append` changes it to 1d, but it still just has 1 element, shape (1,).  Repeated `np.append` is slower (than list append), and hard to use correctly.  I see too many errors when posters try to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to the comments, `np.array` is optimized to be fixed in size. Consecutive resizing of an array using `concatenate`, `vstack`, `hstack`, etc in a `for` loop is less readable and generally less efficient (therefore pointless). Stick to the standard and simple `.append` of a `list`, then make the array at the end:

```
predictions = list()
for index, max_depth_var in zip(range(0,n_mdvs),max_depth_vars):
    #your_code
    predictions.append(your_iteration_array)
predictions = np.array(predictions)
```